# How to get 'encoded' photo data in ezvcard?

Tags: java, android, vcf-vcard

I am using [ez-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/) to parse some VCard files on Android. These VCard files are generated by Android's Default Contact App. Now the problem with these VCard files is that, these files contain data for 'PHOTO' property which was encoded by Android's `Base64` class. So when I use `Photo#getData()` method, I am not getting the right 'decoded' data. So I was looking for some work around so as to get the 'encoded' data string for photo property. Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

**Edit:** I am pretty sure that Base64 class of Android is creating problems because when I write a VCard file using ez-vcard with a photo and try opening this file with Default Contacts App, it gives a VCard parse error but when I write photo string encoded by Android's Base64 class, everything works fine.

To get the encoded photo data string, I also tried using `VCard#getExtendedProperty("PHOTO")` method but it returns **null**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's strange that Android's base64 function works differently.  The base64 algorithm should work the same everywhere, I would think. o_O

If you need to get the raw string value of a PHOTO property, you can create custom scribe and property classes, then register the scribe class with the parser, like so:

```
public class PhotoRawScribe extends VCardPropertyScribe<PhotoRaw> {
  public PhotoRawScribe() {
    super(PhotoRaw.class, "PHOTO");
  }

  @Override
  protected VCardDataType _defaultDataType(VCardVersion version) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected String _writeText(PhotoRaw property, VCardVersion version) {
    return property.getValue();
  }

  @Override
  protected PhotoRaw _parseText(String value, VCardDataType dataType, VCardVersion version, VCardParameters parameters, List<String> warnings) {
    return new PhotoRaw(value);
  }
}

public class PhotoRaw extends SimpleProperty<String> {
  public PhotoRaw(String value) {
    super(value);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String str = 
    "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n" +
    "VERSION:4.0\r\n" +
    "PHOTO:foobar\r\n" +
    "END:VCARD";

    VCardReader reader = new VCardReader(str);
    reader.registerScribe(new PhotoRawScribe());
    VCard vcard = reader.readNext();

    PhotoRaw photo = vcard.getProperty(PhotoRaw.class);
    System.out.println(photo.getValue()); //prints "foobar"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am also a little surprised about Android's Base64 but from what I've experienced, it looks like Android's Base64 works a little different. Or may be, it is just a problem with Android's Contacts App. :)